# Why does `__vfprintf_internal` (`printfn` from the `stdio.h`) force the `$rbp` to jump 6313864 bytes forward on my x86-64 machine?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, x86-64

I am having hard times to figure out what's happening.

Here is what I see in the `gdb` session when dive deeper into a `printfn` from the `stdio.h` on Linux:

> #1  0x00007ffff7ddb81f in __printf (format=) at ./st
> dio-common/printf.c:33
>
> 488 (gdb) p $rbp
>
> 489 $39 = (void *) 0x7ffff798fff8

So far so good.

Let's step into the next call (which is the `__vfprintf_internal`) and see what the %rbp will be then:

> (gdb) p $rbp
>
> 504 $41 = (void *) 0x7ffff7f95780 <*IO_2_1_stdout*

The difference between both values is `6313864` bytes. How is that possible? What is happening?!

P.S. I explicitly use `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to ensure the %rbp preservation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be compiling with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, but it looks like the libc was not.  So `rbp` could have been used as a general purpose register inside the glibc.

Comment: How do you do context-switching then? `%rbp` is to be preserved across threads.

Comment: @Zazaeil You need to save `rbp` on context switch just like any other register.  Whether `rbp` is used as a frame pointer or not doesn't matter for that.

Comment: @Zazaeil: Function calls aren't context switches.  If you were doing a context switch, the kernel would save/restore all the registers.  Or in user-space with fibers or something, it would just look like a normal function call, with all the call-preserved registers (including RBP) unmodified on return.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am actually doing my own userspace fibers with pretty regular `pusq %rbp` & `popq %rbp` (not counting other callee/caller-safe registers). It works well with nested functions but not with `printfn` when I pass some pattern like `printfn("%ith number", 0)`, however `printfn("0th number")` will work as expected. That's were my question comes: I though `printfn` falls with a `segmentation fault` due to broken `rbp`.

Comment: Shall I update the question with my context switching routine though?

Comment: @Zazaeil If that is your question... why didn't you ask it in the first place?  Try not to fall prey to the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).  It's more likely a stack alignment issue.

Comment: Please post your context switching problem as a separate question as it's really a whole 'nother thing.