# Userspace thread a-ka fiber fails to `printfn` when some pattern like `%i` or other is being used

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, fibers

I am playing with my own fibers; more for educational sake.

My platform is x86-64 & Linux.

Here is my context-switching routine

```
__taskflow_switch_cpu_context: 
        // preserve the $rbp, plays together with the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp

        // save the registers 
        pushq %r15
        pushq %r14
        pushq %r13
        pushq %r12
        pushq %rbx

        movq %rsp, (%rdi) // memorize a leaving fiber's $rsp
        movq (%rsi), %rsp // restore a new coming fiber's $rsp 

        // restore the registers in the reverse order
        popq %rbx
        popq %r12
        popq %r13
        popq %r14
        popq %r15

        // preserved %rbp no longer needed
        popq %rbp

        retq
```

The code above works well. It does change a context; it does allow nested functions to be called.. well, almost.

When I have a `printfn("some pattern %i\n", no_matter_how_you_get_an_int())` call inside my fiber, it falls with a segmentation fault. However, the `printfn("no patterns here\n")` works well too.

I though it is because of an %rbp [doing a gigantic jump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74109649/why-does-vfprintf-internal-printfn-from-the-stdio-h-force-the-rbp-t), but seems I was mistaken.

P.S. Once a fiber is created, a correct return address is pushed manually and correct offsets are ensured. Roughly here it is:

```
  /*                                                                               
    x86 stack grows towards lesser memory addresses;                               
    so `res->stack + res->stack_size` is it's very beginning.                      
  */
  uintptr_t *stack = (uintptr_t *)(res->stack + res->stack_size - sizeof(void *));
  // An initial return addess.                                                     
  *stack = (uintptr_t)fn; // A correct return address is there now.
// more unrelated code 
  res->cpu_context->rsp = (res->stack + res->stack_size - sizeof(void *) * 7);  // Ensures some room for the callee/caller-save registers altogether with a parent `rbp`.
```

Once again: since it works fine for "non-`printfn`" calls, I assume the initial stack layout is all right.

P.P.S. `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is there too.

P.P.P.S. As Peter Cordes says in the comments, `movaps` seems to be the problem here (see the attached screenshot from my GDB session). [image]

Comment: Saving/restoring RBP correctly is necessary whether or not you or the caller uses it as a frame pointer.  It's always a call-preserved register in the calling convention, regardless of GCC options.  Your code looks fine, saving / restoring *all* the call-preserved registers including RBP.  The `movq %rsp, %rbp` instruction is harmless but useless (except maybe for debugging if you stop inside this function?)

Comment: When your code crashes, what instruction is it on?  Is it inside printf, on a misaligned `movaps` to or from the stack?  If so, you're probably allocating your fiber stacks misaligned.  (See [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) for an example of the kind of symptom.)   `printfn("no patterns here\n")` compiles to `call puts`, not `call printf`, so it's a different, simpler function in libc that might not happen to use any 16-byte copies.

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, your're right; it is `movaps`. I am not familiar with this instruction yet, will go & study docs. AFAIU, `sub rsp, 8` & `add rsp, 8` must replace my `pushq %rbp` & `popq %rbp` to ensure alignment, but I still have to learn how and why it is needed at the first place. Note: I updated the original post.

Comment: That Q&A is about hand-writing a function that calls printf.  For you, the problem is the address you pass on the first switch to a new fiber: if you call a function, RSP on entry to that function needs to be RSP%16 == 8, as if there was a return address on the stack.

Comment: And is there simple / commonly used way to get it done? Or do I have to ensure it manually also? That's not something obvious to me.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're getting execution started in a new fiber, but probably it's a matter of changing the `sizeof(void*)*7` to a `sizeof(void*)*8` or something if you're using your switch function to get it to "return" somewhere that wasn't actually called.  Since you have a ` - sizeof(void *)` in the initial `uintptr_t *stack`, so it's pointing at readable memory instead of one-past-the-end ready for a push.

Comment: @PeterCordes you made my day, thanks, not only it works, but also I now I know what I did not know and know where to study it.